# Better flow control with re.match in python

Tags: python, regex, match

I've been working with regular expressions lately and I'm looking for a way to improve the flow control when having to use many regular expressions.

This is what things typically look like.

```
result = re.match(string, 'C:')
if result:
    #do stuff here
else:
    result2 = re.match(string, 'something else')

if result2:
    #do more stuff
else:
    result3 = re.match(string, 'and again')

 .
 .
 .
```

What I would really like is to have is something like.

```
MatchAndDo(string, regex_list, function_pointer_list)
```

Or an even better way of doing things.

Comment: So you want to take some action depending on the first regex that matches?

Comment: Yes, I would like to change what my action is depending on which match I get. Some times I want to continue matching, other times I just want the first match.

My thought processes was that with a regex_list and function_pointer_list I could just pop the match if I wanted to continue afterwords.

Comment: Updated my answer based on your last comment. Stoping or continuing is controlled with third parameter in patterns list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish it with

```
patterns = (
    #(<pattern>, <function>, <do_continue>)
    ('ab', lambda a: a, True),
    ('abc', lambda a: a, False),
)

def MatchAndDo(string, patterns):
    for p in patterns:
        res = re.match(p[0], string)
        if res is None:
            continue

        print "Matched '{}'".format(p[0])
        p[1](p[0]) # Do stuff
        if not p[2]:
            return

MatchAndDo('abc', patterns)
```

Note that `re.match()` matches characters from the beginning of string http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html?highlight=re.match#re.match